# Display Uitable data in command window in Matlab

Tags: matlab-figure, matlab-guide, matlab-uitable

I am using a UITABLE to display some data. After displaying the table i want to get the data in command window in matrix form make calculation and again display the  result in a tabular form.
            any 1 pls. help  me..

Answer (score 1):

When you create the table, get its handle:

```
hTable = uitable(...,'Data', dat,...);
```

Make your changes.  Get the data back:

```
dat = get(hTable,'Data');
```

Do some calculations, generating new data.  Update the table:

```
set(hTable,'Data',dat);
```